# Append items to a list from API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, api

Im trying to display currencies in a dropdown list by setting it's html property of all the items(currencies) I retrieve.

Here is my code:

```
var currencyDropdownData = "";
currencyDropdownData.length = 0;
if (confirmationData != null)
{
    currencyDropdownData = confirmationData.Currencies;
    console.log(currencyDropdownData)

    var BudgetSelectData = "";
    //BudgetSelectData += '<option selected value="-1">Please Select</option>'
    for (var currency = 0; currency < currencyDropdownData.length; currency++) {
        console.log(currencyDropdownData[currency].Name);
        BudgetSelectData += '<option value="' + currencyDropdownData[currency].Id + '">' + currencyDropdownData[currency].CurrencyText + currencyDropdownData[currency].Name  + '</option>'
    }

    console.log(BudgetSelectData);

    $('#budgetCurrency').html(BudgetSelectData);        
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="row rowSpace">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Budget (Optional)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-11 noPadding">
                <select validateme="true" class="form-control fullWidth" id="budgetCurrency" placeholder="€ (Euro)" data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="min1">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 noPadding" linkedval="budgetCurrency"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the console I can see the html is being created correctly and each of the currencies are coming back, however nothing is being displayed in the dropdown list

Comment: post the html to

Comment: When you call your javascript? Is the `#budgetCurrency` element already in the page? Try to log to the console `$('#budgetCurrency').length` to verify if the target element is there or not.

Comment: Are you using any library like select-picker for your dropdown?

Comment: Not using a library @bigbounty and yes the budget currency is rendered before this call. Ive posted the html too

Comment: @Smac what's with the data attributes, if your not using a library what are they used for?

Comment: @madalinivascu There is a validation library that im using but I dont think this is the problem

Comment: Again, did you try to check whether your `#budgetCurrency` is already in the page when you are calling your javascript code?

Comment: try using append `$('#budgetCurrency').empty().append(BudgetSelectData);`

Comment: Yes the budget currency is on the page. Ive called the function from the console and it works so I think I just need a set timeout to all for the page to render fully. Thanks

Comment: wrap your code inside jquery dom ready call `$(function() { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you looking for

```
for (var currency = 0; currency < currencyDropdownData.length; currency++) {
    console.log(currencyDropdownData[currency].Name);
    var option = $("option").attr("value", currencyDropdownData[currency].Id)
                   .val(currencyDropdownData[currency].CurrencyText + currencyDropdownData[currency].Name);
    $('#budgetCurrency').append(option);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ive fixed the problem. It was a calling issue